# Display Inner Join Results

Tags: java, sql, inner-join

I have to write a query to

> Select a specific author and list all books for that author. Include each book’s title, year and ISBN.

I have written the query statement as such

```
resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM Authors    "
                        + "INNER JOIN AuthorISBN ON Authors.AuthorID =   AuthorISBN.AuthorID "
                        + "INNER JOIN Titles ON AuthorISBN.ISBN = Titles.ISBN");
```

The results display and sort based on author name, but how do I also have the table display the book title the year and the ISBN? Right now it only displays the authors first name and last name.

Comment: Add them in the list of fields to be returned, after the `SELECT` part

Comment: How does the text book say to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the columns you want in the select clause like this :

```
SELECT Authors.FirstName, Authors.LastName, Titles.year, Titles.ISBN
FROM Authors 
INNER JOIN AuthorISBN ON Authors.AuthorID = AuthorISBN.AuthorID 
INNER JOIN Titles ON AuthorISBN.ISBN = Titles.ISBN
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply write the TableName.ColumnName. I assume, they are in the Titles table so that would be like.

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName,Titles.year,Titles.ISBN
```